# Link not working with jQuery on ipad

Tags: jquery, html, ipad, hyperlink

i have this link :

```
<a class="MultiFile-remove"> x</a>
```

and this jQuery :

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    autoSize: false,
    'afterClose': function() {
        $('#imageName').val(value);
        if (value != "") {
            $('.bestand-naam').append(value + '<a class="MultiFile-remove"> x</a>');
            $('.right-text, .chooseFromGallery').hide();
        }
    }
});

    $(document).on('click', "a.MultiFile-remove", function() {
    $('.right-text, .chooseFromGallery').show();
    $('#imageName').val("");
    $(".bestand-naam").empty();
});
```

This is working fine but on the ipad this not seem to work. 
Anyone knows why it's not working on the ipad?

Comment: where is value in $('#imageName').val(value); from ?

Comment: Does it do something if you add href attribute. <a href="#" class="MultiFile-remove"> x</a> ?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with this added to my stylesheet:

```
a.MultiFile-remove{
cursor: pointer;}
```